# Trying to make my command only accessible by server owner

Tags: discord.js

Trying to make my command only accessible by server owner. Currently anybody is accessible to run the "reset" command and reset all the server stats. Im trying to make it so only myself as the server owner can run this command. Heres the code, your help would be appreciated.

```
var db = require('../db_helper');
const db_checker = require('../db_checker');

module.exports = async (msg) => {
    var existing = db_checker(msg);
    existing.then(async function(result) {
        if (result) {
            var sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE kills_' + msg.guild.id;
                db.query(sql, async function(err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                var sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE players_' + msg.guild.id;
                                db.query(sql, async function(err) {
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                        await msg.channel.send('Your team kill data has been reset');
                                });
                    });
                } else {
                    await msg.channel.send('Goose TK Bot has not been set up on this server. Run `!tkstart` to do so.');
                }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:
`if (!message.member.owner) return;` should do the trick :D

(If not, log message.member, and search for the `owner` property)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two commands

`if (message.author.id !== "YOUR DISCORD ID")`

or

`if(!message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "OWNER ROL NAME"))`

Comment: Thanks man, where would this line of code go. !Struggling to get this working

Comment: You can put that line at the beginning of the command execution. 
`var db = require('../db_helper');
const db_checker = require('../db_checker');

module.exports = async (msg) => {
if (message.author.id == "YOUR DISCORD ID"){
var existing = db_checker(msg);
    existing.then(async function(result) {
        if (result) {
            var sql = ...
} else {
msg.channel.send('you can't run this command ');
}`

Comment: Sorry for taking a long time to answer, the answer is difficult to read since I cannot put code in a comment. I hope it helps you: D